# Guest vm is not able to reach internet behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, virtual-machine

My host in behind a proxy.

Currently, I'm creating virtualbox vms that are not able to get internet.

`HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are well configured, nevertheless, I'm not able to ping at `8.8.8.8` for example...

I say that `HTTP_PROXY` are well configured since I've configured `git` in order to work using a custom proxy, and I'm able to clone external repositories...

**EDIT**

For example, I'm able to get a response using curl command:

```
curl www.google.es
```

However, if I'm trying to poen my browser and access to www.google.es I'm getting this message:

[image]

Browser network configuration is using default system proxy settings

[image]

So, I'm not able to figure out why curl is able to get access to a website and my browser not.

Answer (score 0):

You do realise that "ping",  or rather [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol), is both it's own protocol and definitely not HTTP so  it won't support proxy settings such as the `http_proxy` environment variable.

If using the proxy is mandatory for your internet access you can only use protocols that are both allowed by your proxy server and which can be proxied, such as HTTP, HTTPS, FTP etc. (or those that can be [tunnelled over HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel)) .

Comment: I absolutly agree. I've added some additional words in order to explain on post. Please, could you take a look?

Comment: Probably because an http_proxy environment variable is not the same for Firefox as setting the system proxy in your GUI https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-proxy.html.en ... Also note that how to configure your desktop is mostly off-topic here on ServerFault.